# Inner Join not working in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am trying to join two collections based on the acquisition date:

1. A collection containing mean LST band calculated from MODIS Terra and Aqua,
2. A collection containing Landsat LST with 'ST_B10' as the LST band.
   I want to plot a scatter plot and coefficient of determination (R2) between the two bands, but before that, I need to create an image collection such that each image contains the two bands mentioned before.

```
var terraD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2023-01-01').select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterBounds(geometry)

var aquaD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MYD11A1')
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2023-01-01')
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterBounds(geometry);
  
var landsatD = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2023-01-01')
  .select('ST_B10')
  .filterBounds(geometry);
  
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  min: 13000.0,
  max: 16500.0,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};

// Function to clip each image in the ImageCollection to the ROI
var clipToROI = function(image) {
  return image.clip(geometry);
};

var clipTerra = terraD.map(clipToROI)
Map.addLayer(clipTerra, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'TerraD')

var clipAqua = aquaD.map(clipToROI)
Map.addLayer(clipAqua, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'AquaD')

var clipLandsat = landsatD.map(clipToROI)
Map.addLayer(clipLandsat)

var terraDayCount = clipTerra.size().getInfo();
if (terraDayCount > 0) {
  print('MODIS Terra daytime data is available. Count:', terraDayCount);
} else {
  print('MODIS Terra daytime data is unavailable for the specified date range.');
}
//////////UPSCALE////////////////////

// Function to upscale an image using bilinear interpolation
var upscaleBilinear = function(image) {
  return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
    crs: image.projection(),
    scale: 100  // Set the desired scale (resolution)
  });
};

// Apply bilinear interpolation to the Terra and Aqua datasets
var bilinearTerra = clipTerra.map(upscaleBilinear);
var bilinearAqua = clipAqua.map(upscaleBilinear);
print(bilinearTerra)

// Add the upscaled Terra and Aqua layers to the map with the specified visualization
Map.addLayer(bilinearTerra, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'MODIS Terra (Upscaled)');
Map.addLayer(bilinearAqua, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'MODIS Aqua (Upscaled)');

// Join Terra and Aqua images based on acquisition date
var join = ee.Join.inner().apply({
  primary: bilinearTerra,
  secondary: bilinearAqua,
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'system:time_start',
    rightField: 'system:time_start'
  })
});

//////////////////////MEAN////////////////////////

// Function to calculate the mean of Terra and Aqua images
var calculateMean = function(image) {
  // Get the Terra and Aqua images
  var terraImage = ee.Image(image.get('primary'));
  var aquaImage = ee.Image(image.get('secondary'));
  
  // Calculate the mean of Terra and Aqua images
  var meanImage = (terraImage.add(aquaImage)).divide(2).rename('mean_LST');
  
  // Return the mean image with the acquisition date
  return meanImage.set('system:time_start', terraImage.get('system:time_start'));
};

// Apply the calculateMean function to the joined ImageCollection
var meanCollection = ee.ImageCollection(join.map(calculateMean));

var first = meanCollection.first()

// Add the mean LST layer to the map
Map.addLayer(meanCollection,  landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'mean' )

var matchedCount = meanCollection.size().getInfo();
if (matchedCount > 0) {
  print('Matching Terra and Aqua LST images found. Count:', matchedCount);
} else {
  print('No matching Terra and Aqua LST images found.');
}

print(meanCollection)
print(clipTerra)
print(clipAqua)
print(clipLandsat)

/////////////////Correlation/////////////////

var meanLandsatJoin = ee.Join.inner().apply({
  primary: meanCollection,
  secondary: clipLandsat,
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'system:time_start',
    rightField: 'system:time_start'
  })
});

print(meanLandsatJoin)

// Map a function to merge the bands of each matching pair into a single image.
var mergedCollection = meanLandsatJoin.map(function(image){
  var meanImage = ee.Image(image.get('primary'));
  var landsatImage = ee.Image(image.get('secondary'));
  return meanImage.addBands(landsatImage);
});

print('Size of the merged collection:', mergedCollection.size());

var mergedList = mergedCollection.toList(mergedCollection.size());

// Set the number of random points to be sampled per image.
var numSamplePoints = 1000;

// Iterate over the list indices, get the ith image, sample points,
// and compute the coefficient of determination.
var correlations = ee.FeatureCollection(mergedList.map(function(image) {
  image = ee.Image(image);
  
  // Sample points from the combined image.
  var samplePoints = image.sample({
    region: geometry,
    scale: 100,  // Change this to match the resolution of your images.
    numPixels: numSamplePoints,
    seed: 0,  // Use a fixed seed for reproducibility.
    geometries: true  // Set this to true to get the sampled points as features with geometries.
  });

  // Compute the coefficient of determination.
  var correlation = samplePoints.reduceColumns({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.pearsonsCorrelation(),
    selectors: ['mean_LST', 'ST_B10']
  });

  // Return the correlation as a feature with no geometry.
  return ee.Feature(null, correlation);
}));

print(correlations);

// For visualizing correlation as a scatter plot
var correlationChart = ui.Chart.feature.byFeature(correlations, 'mean_LST', 'ST_B10')
  .setChartType('ScatterChart')
  .setOptions({
    title: 'Correlation between Mean_LST and Landsat LST',
    trendlines: { 0: {
      color: 'CC0000'
    }},  // Draw a trendline for the scatter plot.
    hAxis: {title: 'Mean_LST'},
    vAxis: {title: 'Landsat LST'},
  });

print(correlationChart);
```

I suppose the problem is somewhere in the 'mergedCollection' code. For viewing in GEE:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/dd7e1403ef912dfab78467859bb10f45

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the system:time_start property for the datasets is not the same. I found the solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/422081/join-landsat-and-modis-image-collections-in-earth-engine). Just change the code where you load in the Landsat image collection and it should work.